# How to recreate a Docker Service with same env variables and volumes but under a new name?

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, docker-swarm

I have some Docker Services and I would ideally to have a command that creates a "cloned" service from an existing one.

Something like `command_to_copy_a_service_definition old_service new_service` should therefore lead to the creation of another service `new_service` with a similar config to `old_service`.

I know that [rekcod](https://github.com/nexdrew/rekcod) is able to recreate Docker commands from `docker inspect` but it works on "regular" containers and not on Swarm Service definitions.

Is there something similar for Docker Swarm or any other approach?

**PS:** I would also accept an answer how to rename a Docker Service but [there's another SO question to cover that](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1644#issuecomment-642894080).

Comment: Not sure if "docker rename OLD NEW" works in swarm?

Comment: Docker rename works only on containers and not for services.